# Azure AutoScale Failure Notifications due to no metrics available

Tags: azure, azure-web-roles

In the last few days we have started receiving a lot of emails from Azure saying the following

Subject:

> [AUTOSCALE FAILED] - Autoscale task failed for service_name due to no
>   metrics available

Body of the message:

```
Autoscale has not been able to read any monitoring data ... We recommend monitoring the responsiveness and capacity of your service, to make sure that there are currently enough machines deployed to meet your goals. We will attempt to autoscale as soon as the role instances are available
```

We have not made any recent changes so we are not really sure what this means or whether or not we should take any action. Can anyone shed some light on this?

Comment: We're getting it too. I checked and we definitely did not get any spikes in traffic, so unsure what's going on. I've been running the Autoscale service for a few months now and never heard a peep.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Original question asked a while ago but I started getting this message this morning so I'm adding my experience.

Digging around in the azure portal I was able to see that in fact my cloud service was not scaling so for now I've turned off auto scaling and will be leaving my instances set to my max scale limit.  Continuing to search the portal for clues I noticed a warning at the bottom of my screen, which lead me to this message from Microsoft:

> We are in Extended Recovery for this incident. Starting on 8/5/14 at
>   approximately 16:50 UTC, Cloud Services customers with Auto-Scale
>   services in East US may see errors reporting the inability to read
>   their Auto-Scale metrics data. Engineering teams are deploying their
>   proposed mitigation solution and are continuing to monitor system
>   performance. An update will be provided in 6 hours or as events
>   warrant.

Long story short... For me this wasn't something I did wrong.  It's an issue with the auto scale service that Microsoft has to fix.

Hope this is helpful for others.

Answer (score 5):

You can usually find answers to cryptic errors like this in the Azure Status Page:
http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/status/

Specifically in the ["History"](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/status/#history) section